# Matrices that are similar to their squares

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is an invertible complex $3 \times 3$ matrix such that $A$ and $A^{2}$ are conjugate. What are the possible Jordan forms of $A$?

Again, I have compared eigenvalues for $A$ and $A^{2}$ and resort to cases: if eigenvalues are all distinct, if they are all the same, etc. I might have shared a similar answer previously, but I was wondering if anyone has a better approach to tackling this.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You might note that the square of a Jordan block of size $\ge 2$ for eigenvalue $0$ has null space of dimension $2$, so $A$ can't have such a block
in its Jordan form.  On the other hand, the square of a Jordan block for a nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$ is similar to a Jordan block of the same size for $\lambda^2$.

Comment: $A$ is invertible and so it cannot have a zero eigenvalue, though.

Comment: There exists an invertible $P$ such that $A = PJP^{-1}$, where $J$ is any of the six matrices: $J_{1} =\begin{pmatrix} x & 1 & 0\\ 0 & x & 1 \\  0 & 0 & x \end{pmatrix}$,  $J_{2} =\begin{pmatrix} x & 0 & 0\\ 0 & y & 1 \\  0 & 0 & y \end{pmatrix}$, $J_{3} =\begin{pmatrix} x & 0 &0\\ 0 & x & 1 \\  0 & 0 & x \end{pmatrix}$, $J_{4} = \text{diag}(x, y, z)$, $J_{5} = \text{diag}(x, x, y)$, $J_{6} = \text{diag}(x, x, x)$. Now, $A^{2} = PJ^{2}P^{-1}$. So, it remains to find the Jordan forms of $J^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Another Hint:** There exists a nontrivial pair $(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $x^2=y$ and $y^2=x$.  There exist also two nontrivial triples $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{C}^3$ such that $x^2=y$, $y^2=z$, and $z^2=x$.  (By nontrivial tuples, I mean none of the entries is $0$ or $1$.)  If my counting is right, there should be $11$ possible Jordan normal forms for such matrices, $6$ of which correspond to invertible matrices.

Comment: Here you are comparing the spectrums. $ \{x, y, z \} =\text{Spec}(A) = \text{Spec}(A^{2}) = \{ x^{2}, y^{2}, z^{2}\}$ where $x,y,z$ are nonzero complex numbers. Then breaking down to cases: (1) all the numbers are their own squares, which implies $x =y=z=1$, giving us three possible Jordan forms as $C_{A}(x) = (x-1)^{3}$. (2) Exactly one number, say, $z$ is its own square so that it is 1. In this case we look for non-trivial solutions to $x^{4} - x =0$. The third case is when none of the numbers is 1 and in this case we solve for non-trivial solutions of $x^{8} - x =0$.